# Wave Transmission between two Conjoined Tubes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

If I have two tubes connected to a large reservoir of water, and I cause a disturbance in one of the tubes, will the water in the other tube also become disturbed?

Specific Example: In the diagram shown below, if I drop a marble into tube 1, will there be any waves in tube 2 (I know the water level will rise slightly in tube 2, but I'm only interested in waves/turbulence of the water at the surface)?

Thanks.

[image: Specific Example]

Comment: If tubes 1 & 2 are close enough together, you will be able to measure waves from 1 "bleeding/tunneling" into tube 2. Look up evanescent waves.

Comment: I would expect, with small tube dimensions compared to the reservoir, that the water level in tube 1 would go up measurably first, such that there would be a flow to tube 2 to level them out. Whether the nature of this flow would exhibit turbulence at that surface or not, you'd have to dig deeper to ascertain.

Comment: Acoustic waves will definitely reach water in tube 2, via both water and tube walls. But these may not strong enough to cause observable disturbance of water surface in tube 2.